# How can I mimic a space efficient version of dict in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary

I am working on a dictionary structure where I have a dictionary of documents and each document has a dictionary of words (where each key is word_id (integer) and values are counts) such that:

```
document_dict = { "doc1": {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 100: 1}, "doc2": {10:2, 20:10, 30:2, 41: 19},...}
```

Note that the inner dictionaries are pretty sparse, so even though I have 250K words, I don't expect to have more than 1K keys per document.

In each iteration, I need to sum up a dict of words:counts to one of the documents, e.g. I need to union a new dict of {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 120: 1} to "doc1": {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 100: 1}.

Right now, my implementation runs quite fast, however after 2 hours it runs out of memory (I am using a 40GB server).

The way I was summing up the keys was something like this:

Assume that new_dict is the new word:count pairs that I want to add to doc1 such as:

```
new_dict = {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 120: 1}
doc1 = {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 100: 1}

for item in new_dict:
      doc1[item] = doc1.get(item, 0) + new_dict[item]
```

Then since it was simply impossible to run the code with dictionaries because my dicts get quite large in a very short time, I tried to implement dictionaries as a list of 2 lists: e.g. doc1 = [[],[]] where first list keeps the keys and second key keeps the values.

Now when I want to union 2 structure like this, I first try to get the index of each item of new_dict in doc1. If I successfully obtain an index, it means the key is already in the doc1 so I can just update the corresponding value. Otherwise, it is not in the doc1 yet, so I am append()ing the new key and value to the end of the lists. However this approach runs extremely slow (in dict version, I was able to process up to 600K documents in 2 hours, now I could only processed 250K documents in 15 hours).

So my question is: If I want to use a dictionary structure (key, val) pairs where I need to union keys of 2 dicts and sum their values in each iteration, is there a way to implement this more space efficiently?

Comment: I don't think it's the data structure that's the problem; it's trying to fit X units of stuff into a Y unit bag where X > Y.

Comment: You might have a memory leak that is unrelated to the inner way that dict() operates.  Have you run with a profiler?  I found this article useful http://mg.pov.lt/blog/hunting-python-memleaks.html

Comment: What is growing too large, the dictionary of documents?

Comment: @martineau Actually, both the number of documents that I am storing in the dictionary and both the word:count pairs that I am storing for each document increases over time.

Comment: sounds like a pretty typical map-reduce job?  http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily more space efficient, but I would suggest switching to a disk-based dictionary by using the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module so you don't have to have the entire dictionary in memory at once.

They're very easy to use since they support the familiar dictionary interface, as shown below:

```
import shelve

document_dict = shelve.open('document_dict', writeback=True)

document_dict.update({"doc1": {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 100: 1},
                      "doc2": {10:2, 20:10, 30:2, 41: 19},
                      "doc3": {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 100: 1},})

new_dict = {1:2, 2:10, 10:2, 120: 1}
doc = document_dict.get("doc3", {})  # get current value, if any

for item in new_dict:
    doc[item] = doc.get(item, 0) + new_dict[item]   # update version in memory

document_dict["doc3"] = doc  # write modified (or new) entry to disk
document_dict.sync()  #  clear cache

print document_dict

document_dict.close()
```

Output:

```
{'doc2': {41: 19, 10: 2, 20: 10, 30: 2},
 'doc3': {120: 1, 1: 4, 2: 20, 100: 1, 10: 4},
 'doc1': {1: 2, 2: 10, 100: 1, 10: 2}}
```

Comment: Thanks, shelves look promising. However, I am not quite sure about "you don't have to have the entire dict in memory at once" part. Because from what I understand, shelve will keep all objects in memory (since writeback=True) *unless* I call sync or close calls, right? And even if I call sync() once in a while (e.g. in every 100th document, I could call sync and clear the cache), then I am not sure how I can make sure that I am accessing the true value of an object X. Such as this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3410066

Comment: Yes, calling `sync()` when the `writeback` option was used clears the cache. You can make sure you have the true value of the object and keep the amount of data cached in memory small by calling it after updating the counts for a document as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, it works well and i was able to run my program without any problems!

Comment: Nice to hear that. How's the speed compare? Depending on exactly what you're doing, it might be possible (and worthwhile) to take more advantage of the cache by not syncing and clearing it so often. The other answer's suggestion about using `collections.Counter` would probably also speed things up.

Comment: I think the speed is okay, I was able to proccess 2M documents in 10 hours. Counter approach might be faster to sum the dict values (as I tried them before) but they tend to spend more memory than simple dicts (I am not sure if this is really the case).

Comment: Speed-wise, I meant was it noticeably slower using `shelve` than with real dictionaries. I also realize you may not be able to tell because previously it was running out of memory before finishing. `Counter`s don't use more memory, they're just a dictionary subclass with some convenient methods. You might be able to derive your own `ShelfCounter` to create a something similar that worked in conjunction with the `selve` module (or someone else may have already done it).

Comment: While I'm thinking about it -- one other thing to be aware of about using `shelve` is that it creates a potentially very large database file. So unless you're really using it as a "persistent dictionary" for more than one run, you may want to have your program automatically delete that file when it finishes.